# How do I escape the | (vertical line) character in the StringFormat of a binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, escaping

For example, I have the label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SiteName, StringFormat={}{0}   |  }" />
```

The content of the label should appear as: "A Site Name    |   ".  However, the spaces are omitted, as is the vertical bar.

I tried escaping the bar with the carat (`^`) as mentioned in another resource, but that didn't work.  Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SiteName, StringFormat={}{0}   |  }" />
```

(if you want to be sure the spaces are taken into account :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SiteName, StringFormat='{}{0}   |  '}" />
```

Or, use the `ContentStringFormat` property of the `Label` instead of `StringFormat`.

```
<Label Content="{Binding SiteName}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}   |  " />
```

Comment: I was skeptical but the TextBlock did it! (Aside from some cropped spaces.) Cheers.